# Why is the site SharePoint Stack Exchange not to be found using Bing Search?

Tags: bug, search

Not really sure if this should be posted here:

For some reason I'm unable to find the homepage of SharePoint Stack Exchange using the keywords "SharePoint Stack Exchange".

I'm able to find the stackoverflow and stackexchange sites where SharePoint tags are used. But I cannot seem to find the homepage http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com. Is by any chance in robots.txt defined that the Bing Crawler cannot crawl the homepage?

The reason i'm posting this is because it's possible new visitors are unable to discover the site if it is not te be found using all search engines.

---

<sup>Moderator approved cross site posting:</sup>

[Why is the site SharePoint Stack Exchange not to be found using Bing Search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247639/why-is-the-site-sharepoint-stack-exchange-not-to-be-found-using-bing-search)

---

**EDIT**

And suddenly (as of today), without explanation the site is to be found using Bing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When answering what crawlers do and doesn't do, one is out on thin ice. But you have a point that the start page doesn't show up in the 154 results of your search string on Bing.com.

Facts are that the [robots.txt](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/robots.txt) file disallow all crawling from Yahoo! With the comment saying

```
#
# Yahoo bot is evil.
#
User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /
```

Now, we know that [Bing and Yahoo have a ten year agreement to cooperate in search applications](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing), than there might be a possibility that they share crawl results with each other. If so, and the Yahoo crawler Slurp visits SP.SE it actually follows the robots.txt and shares its non existing result with Bing.

But this is just a qualified guess, where we need to talk to SEO-guys about it, or maybe follow up your question on Meta.SE!

Good catch though!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With your last paragraph, do you mean it will be addressed by the site moderators with the SEO-guys or was it a reference of something I should do?

Comment: @TempaC I thought this would make a great question on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ since I am unable to answer you with facts. Be sure to cross-link it back here, so we can follow the progress. :-)

Comment: ok, I'll repost this question to meta.stackexchange.com. Would be nice to be able to find our subsite on every search engine.

Comment: Anything tagged [tag:bug] on any per-site Meta will be followed up by the devs. There's no need to bring it to Meta SE, unless you have good reason to believe it is affecting many sites in the network.

Comment: Too late TRiG, I've already created the question here :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247639/why-is-the-site-sharepoint-stack-exchange-not-to-be-found-using-bing-search